# Render Xaringan Rmd when using _site.yml file

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a website set up with three files.

_site.yml

```
name: Website
navbar:
  title: Website
  right:
    - text: Home
    - text: Info
output:
  html_document:
    theme: flatly
    highlight: tango
```

index.Rmd

```
---
title: Welcome
output:
  html_document:
    theme: united
    highlight: textmate
---

This is the index.
```

test.Rmd

````
---
title: Test
output:
  html_document:
    theme: united
    highlight: textmate
---

This is the test file.

```{r}
2+2
```
````

If I run `rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd")`, I get an HTML that includes the website header. This is similar to output running `rmarkdown::render_site()`.

[image]

If I remove `_site.yml` file and run the same command, I get the regular HTML output:

[image]

So, `render()` must be using the `_site.yml` when present. Can this be disabled? I would like to create a regular HTML output even when the `_site.yml` file is present. This is especially an issue when I have xaringan presentations and I do not want them rendered with the website header.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to disable it in `rmarkdown`, but you could try the following workaround to temporarily rename it, then name it back afterwards:

```
render_without_site_yml <- function(input, ...) {
  dir <- dirname(input)
  site_yml <- file.path(dir, "_site.yml")
  if (file.exists(site_yml)) {
    newname <- file.path(dir, "_site.yml.save")
    if (file.exists(newname))
      stop("'_site.yml.save' exists!")
    file.rename(site_yml, newname)
    on.exit(file.rename(newname, site_yml))
  }
  rmarkdown::render(input, ...)
}
```

Comment: Hacky! But, this is easier than where I was going. I was considering going into the `render()` function and look where `_site.yml` is used. And possibly modify the function.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `output:` specified in individual .Rmd files overrides the default in `_site.yml`.

So my _site.yml contains

```
output:
  html_document:
    highlight: textmate
    toc: true
    css: "assets/doc.css"
    include:
      after_body: assets/footer-doc.html
```

And my xaringan presentation contains

```
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: 'assets/slide.css'
    lib_dir: libs
    include: NULL
```

And if I call `render_site()`, md and Rmd files without any `output:` specified takes the defaults from **_site.yml**, gets **doc.css** styles and add custom footer **footer-doc**.

My xaringan presentations with custom `output:` is rendered through `moon_reader` and gets **slide.css** style and no footer is attached.

The output files are rendered and moved to destination folder. But I get this kind of warnings for xaringan slides:

```
In file.rename(output, output_dest) :
  cannot rename file './source/slide_dge.html' to './dest/slide_dge.html', reason 'No such file or directory'
```

I do not have an explanation for this yet.

In addition, if I render the xaringan Rmd alone (in presence of **_site.yml**) using `rmarkdown::render('xaringan.Rmd')`, this results in an incorrect output.